# Amazon RDS On-Demand DB instance to Reserved instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We currently have 3 on-demand rds instances running and we're planning to move each instances to reserved ones.

Upon purchase of the reserved instances, what migration steps should be done to move from the on-demand to the reserved?
Can a snapshot from the on-demand and restore snapshot to the reserved do the process?

I've read about EC2's reserved instances and people said that it's a matter about billing. Is it the same on RDS?

Comment: This link should help: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=232310

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, reserved instances are a billing construct wherever they're available (RDS, EC2, ElastiCache, etc.). No changes are necessary for the instance - if you buy a m3.large instance in us-west-2a, one of your m3.large instances in us-west-2a will immediately begin charging at the lower hourly rate.

Comment: I see. The AWS interface when purchasing a reserved instance looks like you're purchasing for a "new" instance that's different from any existing instances you have. And I haven't ready this anywhere on the RDS docs. Big thanks for this!

Comment: It's buried somewhere in the docs but a frequent source of confusion. I've seen this question frequently here.

Comment: Yeah, I've read one here but it's about EC2. I never knew they apply the same process so I asked just to clarify. Of course RDS are merely EC2 instances too with access to the box all stripped out.